# Straighten a rotated object in 3DS Max

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

I have an object that has been rotated and attached to another. I now want to detach this object and rotate it so that it is straight again.

The object consists of multiple boxes so surely there is a way to rotate it so that one of the faces is straight along the z axis?

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is regarding 3D modeling.  Please commit to the [site proposal for 3D Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics)

Answer (score 2):

Only if you have the history on the object. Once you bake it, freeze the transforms or combine it with another object, it loses the orientation it began with. If that is the case, and the object is currently at 0,0,0 in the rotation axis, history is the only way to get it back.

If you are at that point, you would have to adjust by eye...

It is good practice to always duplicate objects and hide them as 'spares'. You'll be surprised how often that saved spare part will bail you out of trouble. Another trick is to always rotate things by an even number, that way if you have to return it by eye, it is easier to re-line up.

Comment: Thanks John, I'm just dubious as to why it can't do a bit of trigonometry against one a selected polygon and rotate against it's angle. Seems like a basic thing to do in such a complex package.

Comment: I'm more familiar with Maya, there are tools that can orient (rotate) constrain to surfaces, but they work per object, not on a selected surface face normals.